# Can I create a response object in java without creating a servlet?

Tags: java, html, ajax

Can I create a response object in java without creating a Servlet? I have a regular java class right now called Menu. It contains not only my menus for my application but it also contains my CRUD functionality that is tied to the database. Which works fine on the console. What I want to do now is to display the result set on a webpage. I want to use AJAX (no frameworks like jQuery etc.) to capture the information from the result set. In the Menu class I am going to convert the extracted information into a Json string with Jackson databinding (object mapper). I want to use a PrintWriter to send this information back to AJAX. I am assuming I need a response object. Do I have to re-write my Menu class as a Servlet or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Of course you can _create_ a response object, but you're asking more about delivering that to an HTTP client. For that you'll need some sort of HTTP server functionality, whether that's writing your own with sockets, hand-writing Servlets (usually the worst idea), using a framework that uses Servlets under the hood (Spring MVC, Dropwizard), or using some fancy new setup like Netty (Spring Webflux).

Answer (score 0):

For querying data from server you need to have a resource which has

- http url
- can accept a form of request as input
- can give response based on business logic in menu crud class.

For this querying as you said you can do with ajax call to this servlet with specified url pattern from your frontend webpage.

In short servlet will be essential. It can handle all http method types like get post and so on.

So you can map your crud methods to your servlet methods

eg :

- doGet - querying items.
- doPost- creation of item.
- doDelete- delete an item.
  and so on.

further you will call your crud methods from these servlet do* methods.
for example refer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/servlet-crud-operation-with-example/

Hope this helps.